# Export Google Colab Notebook to csv file

Tags: google-colaboratory

I need to download the results of a for loop on Google Colab to a csv file, but I haven't been able to do it.

This is my for loop:

```
for num in range(1, 101):
  if ( num%2 == 0 and num%6 != 0) or (num%3 ==0 and num%6 != 0):
    list = print(num)
```

The Notebook is called AHW1.ipynb

I tried:

```
from google.colab import files
files.download("AHW1.csv")
```

What can I do to download the results of this for loop as a csv file?

Answer (score 0):

```py
# data analysis libraries 
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# visualization libraries
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline

# ignore warnings
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.